# UIPopOver from infoButton on UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, ios-simulator, uipopovercontroller

Hi i am trying to show a popover from info button click which is on a uitablecell. But when i run it the simulator just hangs up. Following is my code

This is in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
            UIButton *helpButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark ] ;
            helpButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 16, 200 ,15);
            helpButton.tag = 458;
            [helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doHelp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:helpButton];
```

My doHelp Method

```
-(void)doHelp : (id)sender{
  testviewcontroller=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
  popTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 80, 120)  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  popTable.delegate = self;
  popTable.dataSource = self;

  testviewcontroller.view=popTable;


  navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:testviewcontroller];

  pop=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navController];


  // navController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem=searchItem;
  //  navController1.navigationBar.topItem.title=@"Reporting Type";
  navController.navigationBarHidden=true;

  [pop presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
  [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(250,107)];

 }
```

Any hep will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a iphone app or ipad app ?

Comment: Without adding the uinavigation controller initialize the popover with uiviewcontoller object and check whether the same issue occurs or not.

Comment: tried, still hangs up...

Comment: oh!! i found the answer... i had forgotten to include poptable in cellForRowAtIndexPath method... how silly... thanx anyways.